# conflict between Jquerys

Tags: javascript, html

i have a problem when i made lot of jquery fonctions on the same file it did not work. 
I try to use de jQuery.noConflict() fonction but it didn't work(maybe i didn't use it in a good way or i use it in a wrong place) how can i use noconflict fonction in my example code?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.ui.core.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.ui.widget.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.ui.mouse.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.ui.tabs.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function()
        {
           var jQueryTabs1Opts =
           {
              event: 'click',
              collapsible: false
           };
           $("#jQueryTabs1").tabs(jQueryTabs1Opts);
        });

</script>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#example').dataTable( {
                "aaSorting": [[ 4, "desc" ]]
            } );
        } );
</script>
```

Comment: But.... **Why** do you import jQuery more than once ?

Comment: I don't see `noConflict` anywhere in this code.

Comment: Because i want to use Jquerytabs and also a javascript fonction to sort my table (in any jquery tab i want to make a table with to possiblity to sort it just by cliking on colonne)

Comment: I delete the noConflict fonction because it doesn't work for me.But i am not sure i use it in a good way

Comment: how can i use noconflict fonction in my example code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the solution .The solution is to use noConflict function like that :

```
<script>
var jq172 = jQuery.noConflict();
jq172(document).ready(function()
{
   var jQueryTabs1Opts =
   {
      event: 'click',
      collapsible: false
   };
   jq172("#jQueryTabs1").tabs(jQueryTabs1Opts);
}); 
</script>
```

Comment: No, that's not the solution but a bad hack. You shouldn't import jQuery twice.

Comment: No i can :D It works for me , if i delete the                                         <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script> the datatable will not works and if i delete the other the JQuerytabs will not apear

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work if you remove the duplicate import.

Remove this line :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
```

Pay attention to the version of jQuery needed by the UI libraries you import.