# Conflict between Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [conflict between Jquerys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14407146/conflict-between-jquerys)

i have a problem when i made lot of jQuery functions on the same file it did not work. In any jQuery tab i want to make a table with to possibility to sort it just by clicking on colonne.
I used this to add jQueryTabs:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
```

and this for the sorting fonction:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
```

I try to use de jQuery.noConflict() fonction but it didn't work , where is the problem ?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
jq172.noConflict();
   jq172(document).ready(function()
    {
       var jQueryTabs1Opts =
       {
          event: 'click',
          collapsible: false
       };
       jq172("#jQueryTabs1").tabs(jQueryTabs1Opts);
    }); 
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.ui.core.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.ui.widget.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.ui.mouse.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.ui.tabs.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery('#example').dataTable( {
            "aaSorting": [[ 4, "desc" ]]
        } );
    } );
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
```

Comment: jQuery doesn't create a variable named `jq172`, I believe.

Comment: Look at your browser's console, I imagine this line: `jq172.noConflict();` is throwing an error because `jq172` doesn't exist.

Comment: Did you write jquery.js or is that just another version of the jquery source? Where does jq172 come from?

Comment: Perhaps you wanted `jq172 = jQuery.noConflict()`?

Comment: Next time please try updating your existing question(s) with your progress so far instead of reposting them, this way the progress and answers from your previous question aren't lost.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté on the other hand, this way, you can downvote twice ;-)

Comment: @JanDvorak I didn't downvote any of these but your comment still made me laugh rofl `=]`

Comment: Welcome to [SO]; read the [faq], and the [about](http://stackoverflow.com/about) page. Instead of opening a new question with the same content, fix the issues with your question.

Comment: Or how about you try to get everything on obe version of jQuery! What a waste of memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do this:

```
<script>
var jq172 = jQuery.noConflict();
   jq172(document).ready(function()
    {
       var jQueryTabs1Opts =
       {
          event: 'click',
          collapsible: false
       };
       jq172("#jQueryTabs1").tabs(jQueryTabs1Opts);
    }); 
</script>
```

That said, I've never tried this, and I don't know how browser loading and caching would affect this. I'm not confident that the first `jQuery.noConflict` will call the 1.7.2 library. You might be better off using a library like [Require.js](http://requirejs.org/) to load and separate your modules, despite its coding and setup overhead.

Comment: browser caching? That's one of the things you usually disable on your development environment's browser(s). RequireJS is good for asynchronously loading libraries, but concerning modern browsers which allow for a lot more of parallelism there isn't much of a difference in loading speed. Placing the script(s) at the bottom of the page should provide basically the same experience as the DOM structure will be already rendered and the scripts loaded through speculative parsing.

Comment: Even if i add var jq172 = jQuery.noConflict(); the sort of the table didn't work

Comment: @FabrícioMatté It's not about the loading or the parallelism - it's about the namespacing of libraries. You could feasibly run multiple versions of libraries and just assign them to different variables using require. That means that you could do `var jq172 = require('jquery.1.7.2.js'); jq172('#myselector').animate()` or something like that. Without it, you have to make a call to `jQuery.noConflict`. If everything's cached and loaded, which library will that command call? If this is a real problem, you may not catch it in development with caching disabled, but users will catch it in production.

Comment: @lunchmeat317 Oh I see. Also, from what I remember, you can put a callback as a second parameter when requiring jQuery that works as a DOM ready handler if I remember correctly.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté It's worth noting that I'm actually not sure how the browser would respond to a situation like this. I don't know if page loading/rendering and HTML source parsing is suspended for a javascript operation in the head. If it is, then I don't think there would be a problem, but I don't know enough about how browsers handle that to be really sure. :-) And actually, I just remembered - require.js has a modified jQuery library for use with it, so require.js may not work for this user. My bad. *sheepish*

Comment: @lunchmeat317 Script loading is synchronous - it halts the DOM rendering until the script is fully loaded and executed. It does not stop speculative parsing from downloading the rest of the page and resources, but these won't be parsed into the DOM until the obtrusive `<script>` tags finish loading. `RequireJS` in the other hand, loads scripts asynchronously, this way it doesn't block the page rendering.

Answer (score 0):

Try assigning no conflict into a variable.

```
var jq172 = jQuery.noConflict();
var jQuery2 = jQuery.noConflict();
```

Comment: The problem with this is that you're calling noConflict from the same library, meaning that `jq172` and `jQuery2` are two references to one object.